# JIRA spent time in last month report

Tags: jira, time-tracking

Is it possible to generate a report of time spent in last month?
Now when I try to generate Time Tracking Report is generating a report for all time, there are no date start/end filters.

[image]

I was using YouTrack and there it's very easy to generate such report.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Chrome extension that integrates with your JIRA instance named 'JIRA Assistant' which provides a very easy to use 'Time Tracking' functionality.
You could use that for your time tracking requirements for individuals or group of users or teams.

This has the provision of giving custom time-ranges!

Providing a screenshot of how it looks like with just Chrome browser!

[image]

It has an old and a new UI that provides certain features in both the versions of the tool/extension. Hope this helps!